# I got ImportError and cannot import name Httpresponse from django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying to build a website and I got this error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Httpresponse' from 'django.http' (C:\Users\vivek\Envs\asvc\lib\site-packages\django\http\__init__.py)
```

I even tried from django.http

Comment: Could you check if the name is correct? Check for misspelled imports. :)

Comment: Nope bro no misspelled imports

Comment: The correct import is `from django import HttpResponse`. Make the `R` uppercase.

Comment: Questions about a problem that can no longer be reproduced or that was caused by a simple typographical error are **off-topic**. This should be closed as a typo question.

Answer (score 3):

Python is case sensitive, so even though there's no misspelling, the correct sentence would be

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
```